# Why Tags URLs are not SEO friendly in opencart?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, opencart

In opencart, my main products URLs and category URLs are SEO friendly. But tags URLs are not SEO friendly.

My product URLs are like this.
`http://www.example.com/men-branded-zip-up-hoody-full-sleeve-fleece-hoodie-top`

Category URLs are like this
`http://www.example.com/electronics`

But Tags URLs are like this
`http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/search&tag=men%20hoodie`

That is not SEO friendly.

Please help me to rewrite URL for Tags links.

Answer (score 0):

> In opencart my main products URLs and category URLs are SEO friendly. But tags URLs are not SEO frindly.

You mean "user friendly", search engines really don't care either way. In fact, you have more control over indexing (with the tools provided in Google Search Console) if you are using URL parameters.

> But Tags URLs are like this `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/search&tag=men%20hoodie`

Tag (or search) URLs are excluded from crawling in `robots.txt`:

```
Disallow: /*?route=product/search
```

So, they won't be crawled (and therefore indexed) by search engines anyway. It is generally preferable to exclude your search results from being crawled/indexed - this is a Google recommendation.

Reference:
http://searchengineland.com/google-warning-against-letting-your-search-results-get-indexed-10709